# Pandas: What's the quickest way to find spaces + unusal characters in column values?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-cleaning

in Pandas, I have a column col_one that originally contained comma-seperated values in each cell.

```
['a, b, e, g, o', 'a, b, d', 'a, b, c, f, g', 'a, b, c, f', 'a, c, e', 'a, b, c, o', 'b, c, h, n', 'a, b, c, g, o', 'a, b, c, f', 'a, b, c, g, h, o', 'b', 'a, b, f, m', 'a, b, c, g, h', 'a, b, d, f, g', 'a, c, n', 'j', 'b, c, f', 'a, b, g, l', 'b', 'b', 'a, b, d, e ', 'a, b, c', 'a, b, e, g', 'a, b, c, d, f, g', 'd, k, l', 'a, b, c, f, g ', 'a, b, c, f', 'a, b, c, d,  g', 'b, d, e', 'b, d', 'a', 'b, o', 'c, o', 'b, c, o', 'c', 'a, g, i', 'b, c, n', 'a, b', 'b, c, o, n', 'b, c, h', 'a, b, c, f, g, h', 'a, b, c, d', 'a, b, d', 'a, e, g', 'a, b, c, e, g, k, m', 'b, c, o', 'a, b, f, k', 'd, l', 'a, b, l', 'a, b, c', 'a', 'c, d, g, l', 'b, d, e, o', 'b, d', 'a, b, c, d, e, f, o', 'b', 'a, b, c, f', 'b, c, g', 'b, c, g, k', 'a', 'c', 'b, c, o', 'b, c, n, o']
```

I used `str.split(', ').explode().value_counts() .reset_index()` to get an count of the individual letters. But in the resulting table, some letters appear twice, presumably because the string contains trailing spaces. **Unfortunately these are not visible in the the Jupyter Notebook display of the resulting table as they are just blanks.**

Using this

```
col_one_list = df["letter"].tolist()
print (col_one_list)
```

gave me a list of all values counted. In this list, I was able to spot a trailing space ("g "). But how could I have done this better?

```
['b', 'a', 'c', 'g', 'd', 'f', 'o', 'e', 'n', 'h', 'l', 'k', 'm', 'j', 'g ', ' g', 'e ', 'i']
```

Comment: You can use `str.findall("\w")` instead of `str.split`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the white spaces with `''` then continue with
`split-explode-value_counts`, or you can also use `get_dummies`:

```
s.str.replace('\s+', '').str.get_dummies(',').sum()
```

Output:

```
a    36
b    49
c    35
d    15
e     9
f    13
g    18
h     5
i     1
j     1
k     4
l     5
m     2
n     5
o    13
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

I would look at your exploded series to see which values have trailing spaces:

```
letter_series = pd.Series(['b', 'a', 'c', 'g', 'd', 'f', 'o', 'e', 'n', 'h', 'l', 'k', 'm', 'j', 'g ', ' g', 'e ', 'i'])    
letter_series.str.endswith(' ')
```

or see which values are longer than one character

```
letter_series.str.len()
```

Comment: I like the second method, as it would catch any other invisble characters (if existing)